# Extracting a string between the first and second comma in a specific line in all files in a directory

Tags: regex, string, batch-file, command, findstr

I am trying to extract a string that is located between the first and second comma in a specific line in a series of text files (subtitle files). The text files are formatted this way:

Subtitles01.txt

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour
Style: Default, Estrangelo Edessa, 57, &H00FFFFFF
Style: Title1, Arno Pro, 65, &H00606066
```

Subtitles02.txt

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour
Style: OP Eng, Arno Pro, 45, &H00100F11
Style: ED Romaji, Nueva Std Cond, 46, &H00FFFFFF
```

Subtitles03.txt

```
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour
Style: OP Eng, Estrangelo Edessa, 45, &H00100F11
Style: Default, Arno Pro, 45, &H00100F11
Style: ED Romaji, Nueva Std Cond, 46, &H00FFFFFF
```

What I want to achieve here is extract the Fontname for each line that start with "Style: " and then determine which subtitles contain the fonts I want in a non-repeat manner. So essentially the end result would be output to a textfile like the following;

```
Subtitles01.txt: Estrangelo Edessa
Subtitles01.txt: Arno Pro
Subtitles02.txt: Arno Pro
Subtitles02.txt: Nueva Std Cond
Subtitles03.txt: Estrangelo Edessa
Subtitles03.txt: Arno Pro
Subtitles03.txt: Nueva Std Cond

Only Subtitles03.txt is needed.
```

Since Subtitles03.txt contains all the fonts in Subtitles01.txt and Subtitles02.txt, only Subtitles03.txt is needed. The goal is to use the least amount of files to find the unique fonts in all the files. I have came up with the following batch script using **findstr** to extract the lines starting with "Style: " but I am stuck beyond that.

```
@echo off
findstr /B /C:"Style:" *.txt > results.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Found! logged files into results.txt
) else (
    echo No matches found
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it would be much easier to use some other language besides batch, or at least use non-native utilities. But here is a pure native batch solution.

I don't see how FINDSTR regex will help with this problem. It cannot extract a portion of the matching line like many other non-native batch regex utilities.

You can use FOR /F to extract the fonts from each file:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('findstr /lb "Style:" file.txt') do echo font=%%A
```

You can use environment variables to come up with a list of unique fonts. Define variables with the font name in the variable name, all prefixed with `font_`. Only one variable can be defined for a given name. The assigned value does not matter. You can then use `set font_` to list all the unique font names. The number of unique names can be counted, or the actual font name can be parsed out (remove the `font_` prefix).

The tricky part is establishing the minimum set of files required to cover the complete set of unique font names. I imagine someone could come up with an efficient solution. I've just employed a brute force recursive permutation method: I count the number of unique fonts found in each permutation and compare the number to the total number of unique fonts. I have added a few shortcuts to not proceed down a particular permutation path if I've already found a smaller complete set than the current set.

The code could be simpler if I used SETLOCAL in my recursion, but batch is limited to only 32 levels of SETLOCAL. I wanted a solution that could support more than 32 files, although I'm a bit worried about performance with that many files.

***Edit*** *-I fixed a bug in my `:permuteFiles` routine that surfaced once I had more than 3 files*

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::Make sure there are no font_ variables defined
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set font_ 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

::Read all the Subtitle files and
:: - create an "array" of file names
:: - create a file of font names for each input file
:: - create an "associative array" of unique font names
:: - List the available file/font pairs in the final results
:: - List the unique fonts in the final results
set fileCount=0
>results.txt (
  echo Available fonts
  echo ----------------------------
  for %%F in (subtitles*.txt) do (
    set /a totalFiles+=1
    set "file_!totalFiles!=%%F"
    3>"%%F.fonts" (
      for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('findstr /lb "Style:" "%%F"') do (
        set "font_%%A=1"
        >&3 echo %%A
        echo %%F:%%A
      )
    )
  )
  echo(
  echo Unique fonts
  echo ----------------------------
  for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set font_') do (
    set "font=%%A"
    echo !font:~5!
  )
)

::Count the number of unique fonts
for /f %%N in ('set font_ ^| find /c /v ""') do set uniqueFonts=%%N

::Test all the permutations
set /a minFileCount=%totalFiles%+1
for /l %%N in (1 1 %totalFiles%) do (
  call :permuteFiles %%N 0 ""
)

::List the required files in the final results
>>results.txt (
  echo(
  echo The following files contain the complete set of unique fonts:
  echo -------------------------------------------------------------
  for %%N in (%minFileList:~1,-1%) do echo !file_%%N!
)
type results.txt

::Cleanup
del subtitles*.txt.fonts
exit /b


:permuteFiles  fileNumber  fileCount  fileList
if %1==%totalFiles% (
  if %2 gtr 0 call :testPermutation %2 %3
  set /a fileCount=%2+1
  if !fileCount! lss !minFileCount! call :testPermutation !fileCount! "%~3,%1"
) else (
  set /a nextFile=%1+1
  if %2 gtr 0 call :permuteFiles !nextFile! %2 %3
  set /a "nextFile=%1+1, fileCount=%2+1"
  if !fileCount! lss !minFileCount! call :permuteFiles !nextFile! !fileCount! "%~3,%1"
)
exit /b


:testPermutation  fileCount  fileList
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set font_ 2^>nul') do set "%%A="
for %%N in (%~2) do (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("!file_%%N!.fonts") do set "font_%%A=1"
)
for /f %%N in ('set font_ ^| find /c /v ""') do if %%N==%uniqueFonts% (
  set minFileList=%2
  set minFileCount=%1
)
exit /b
```

Here are the results using your example input:

```
Available fonts
----------------------------
Subtitles01.txt: Estrangelo Edessa
Subtitles01.txt: Arno Pro
Subtitles02.txt: Arno Pro
Subtitles02.txt: Nueva Std Cond
subtitles03.txt: Estrangelo Edessa
subtitles03.txt: Arno Pro
subtitles03.txt: Nueva Std Cond

Unique fonts
----------------------------
 Arno Pro
 Estrangelo Edessa
 Nueva Std Cond

The following files contain the complete set of unique fonts:
-------------------------------------------------------------
subtitles03.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: use this one:

```
^Style:\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*([^,]+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*
```

Comment: The `\s` are superflous. `[^,]` matches everything that `\s` matches. Otherwise, good. :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are apparently on a platform which doesn't have `awk` or Perl installed by default, but you may still want to consider installing one of those tools, especially if you need to perform similar tasks in the future.

```
awk -F, '/^Style:/ { print FILENAME ":" $2 }' *.txt
```

Or with Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$1\n" if m/^Style: [^,]*,([^,]*)/' *.txt
```

The subsequent optimization (to remove any files which overlap with other matching files) would not be hard to do in either language.  Perl scales better to bigger and more diverse tasks, so if you are unfamiliar with both, it would be my first recommendation (at the cost of a longer and somewhat more bumpy learning curve, and then you should consider Python, too).

Answer (score 1):

If "The goal is to use the least amount of files to find the unique fonts in all the files", then the Batch file below solve your problem:

**EDIT**: Ops! I had a small bug in my previous code: I should not delete the *whole* file when processing each Fontname contained in the target File, just subtract *that* Fontname from the file count. I fixed the bug in the code below (that is simpler now, indeed):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create "Files with Fontnames" and "Fontnames in Files" sets, 
rem and FileCount with number of Fontnames in each file
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%b in ('findstr /B /C:"Style:" %%a') do (
      set File[%%~Na]=!File[%%~Na]!"%%b",
      set Fontname[%%b]=!Fontname[%%b]!%%~Na,
      set /A FileCount[%%~Na]+=1
   )
)

echo Fonts by File:
set File[
echo/
echo/

echo Following files provide all fonts:

rem For each non-processed "File with Fontnames"
:nextFile

   rem Process File with larger number of Fontnames first
   set fontCount=0
   for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set FileCount[') do (
      if %%b gtr !fontcount! (
         set fontCount=%%b
         set nextFile=%%a
      )
   )
   if %fontCount% equ 0 goto exit

   rem Show this file as result
   echo File %nextFile%.txt

   rem For each Fontname in this file
   for %%a in (!File[%nextFile%]!) do (
      rem Subtract this Fontname from the Files that include it
      for %%b in (!Fontname[%%~a]!) do (
         set /A FileCount[%%b]-=1
      rem and delete this Fontname
      set Fontname[%%~a]=
      )
   )

rem Go back to process next file
goto nextFile

:exit
```

For example:

```
Fonts by File:
File[Subtitles01]=" Estrangelo Edessa"," Arno Pro",
File[Subtitles02]=" Arno Pro"," Nueva Std Cond",
File[Subtitles03]=" Estrangelo Edessa"," Arno Pro"," Nueva Std Cond",


Following files provide all fonts:
File Subtitles03.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand how your logic is supposed to work, but your code certainly does not. Try adding a unique font to 02, - the answer should then be 01,02. Then add a unique font to 03 and the answer should be 02,03. Finally add a unique font to 01 and the answer should be 01,02,03. Your code does not print out the complete set of unique fonts, nor does it print out a set of file names that contain all the unique fonts.

Comment: Yes. My code had a small bug, it was fixed now. I think the OP did not requested the set of unique fonts, but it is very easy to add that in my code...

Comment: Still not there. Try a test with 01:A,B  02:C,D  03:E,F  04:A,C,E. The correct answer is 01,02,03. Your code gives 04,01,02,03. Note - I had a bug in my code that failed the same test that is fixed now :-)  But I can't see how to make your algorithm work. The order in which you process shouldn't affect the outcome, though it could impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Style: (.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)
```

Then, just get the second matched result. Just ensure that you use the **whole** string. Not just starting from the parenthesis.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed that there was actually four blocks, with three commas, instead of three blocks, with two commas. Code is now working and fixed.

Comment: Nope. [That doesn't work.](http://regexr.com?31fnc) Remember that `.` matches "any character", **including** commas. You need to make it non-greedy, or not match commas. (`[^,]*` would work here.)

Comment: @Li-aungYip I misread the example, and I missed a comma. My code has been fixed, and has been deemed working [here](http://regexr.com?31fnf). I would appreciate if you removed downvote. (:

Comment: Still not very robust. You're relying on there being exactly four fields - not really a good idea. A more robust version might look like `^Style: [^,]+,[^,]+,.+$`.